# Creating row in child table using jpa when we have a row in parent table

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `addr1` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addr2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

primary key of `addr1` is set from address table. I created my entities using joined inheritance as

```
@Entity
@Table(name="addr1")
public class Addr1 extends Address {
    @Column(name="addr2")
    private String addr2;
    // getters and setters follows
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false, length = 250, insertable = true)
    private String address;
    // getters and setters follows
}
```

Now I have a row in address table with id 2. I want to inset a row in addr1 table with same id (2). I had tried

```
Address addr = em.getReference(Address.class, new Integer(4));
Addr1 addr1 = new Addr1(addr);
addr1.setAddr2("dsdsd");
em.persist(addr1);
```

but I am getting an error

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: Addr1

Please help me.

Regards,
Praveen

Comment: can you show what this constructor in your code does ? new Addr1(addr);

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. Inheritance implies a *is-a* relationship. Your entity instances can thus be either a bare `Address`, or an `Addr1`. And a Java object can't change its type. You can't take an object of type Object, and ask the JVM to change its type and make it an object of type String instead. It's the same here.

If you need to do that, then you should use composition, not inheritance: an Address can *have* an Addr1. And you should thus have a OneToOne association beteween Address and Addr1, instead of an inheritance relationship.